# Is there an epsilon-delta definition of the second derivative?

Tags: calculus

Is there an epsilon-delta definition for the second derivative?

I know that there is such a definition for the first derivate $f'(x)$ which can be derived from the limit $f'(x) = \lim_{y\rightarrow x} \frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}$ for a function $f:D\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$:

$$\forall \epsilon > 0\, \exists \delta > 0\, \forall y \in D\setminus \{x\}:|y-x|<\delta \Rightarrow \left|\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}-f'(x)\right|<\epsilon$$

So $f'(x)$ can be described as the number which fulfills the above statement. Is there a similar statement for the second derivative?

**Update:** This [MSE thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/161910/most-general-a-subseteq-mathbb-r-to-define-derivative-of-f-a-to-mathbb-r) shows that there are different definitions for the derivative (and thus for the second derivative). So I want to make my question more concrete:

*My definition of derivation:* Let be $f:D\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ with $D\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ *arbitrary*. Let $D^*$ be the set off all points $x\in D$ for which there is at least one sequence $(x_n)$ in $D\setminus\{x\}$ with $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} x_n=x$. I define the limit $\lim_{y\rightarrow x\ ,y\in D\setminus\{x\}} {f(y)-f(x) \over y-x}$ as the first derivation for a given $x\in D^*$ (if the limit exists).

*My definition of the second derivative:* Let be $f:D\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ with $D\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ arbitrary. We call $f''(x)$ the second derivative if there exists an open interval $x\in O\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ so that $f$ is differentiable on $O\cap D$ and $f''(x)$ is the first derivative of the function $f': (O\cap D)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}:x\mapsto f'(x)$ at the point $x$ (which also means that $x\in(O\cap D)^*$).

*My question:* Is there a statement $\forall \epsilon > 0: \exists \delta > 0: A(\epsilon, \delta, f, x, c)$ for $f:D\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ ($D\subseteq \mathbb{R}$) and $c,x\in\mathbb{R}$ which is equivalent to the statement that $f$ is differentiable on a set $x\in O\cap D$ where $O$ is an open interval and that $c$ is the second derivative of $f$ at $x$?

I also will accept answers where you need more restrictions to the question. For example you might want to use the value of the first derivative $f'(x)$ (at the same point where you want to define the second derivative) in your statement or you want to restrict $f$ on functions with open domains or domains which are intervals. In this case I will accept your answer and open a new thread asking for a more general solution.

*Please notice that there is a community wiki post where I want to collect all the progress we made so far.*

Comment: Just get the first derivative, then use the definition on that one. =)

Comment: @PeterTamaroff Yeah, this would be fine. Is there a epsilon-delta definition without using the first derivative?

Comment: @tampis It may be hard/unnatural considering the second derivative is *defined* as the derivative of the derivative. Perhaps one could nest one epsilon-delta definition into another but that is the kind of thing they only do to prisoners at Guantanamo Bay...

Comment: I don't have the time to try it, but I wonder if the [double mean value theorem](http://www.math.ntnu.no/~hanche/blog/doubly-mean.pdf) (pdf) could be used to make such a definition?

Comment: @tampis: You must use at least the _value_ of $f'(x)$. Otherwise how do you distinguish between functions with the same second derivative but not the same first derivative?

Comment: In order that the second derivative exist at $x$, it is necessary that the first derivative exist in an entire neighborhood of $x$.  How can an epsilon-delta statement ensure that?

Comment: @RagibZaman And I thought that MSE was the ONE place I could go to get away from political BS. I guess I was wrong.

Comment: @tampis I don't understand the last example. How is the function defined on $\mathbb R\setminus (A\cup B)$? Why you do not consider all pairs $h,k\in \mathbb R$? For example, take a fixed $k\in A$ and a very small $h\notin A$. Then the difference quotient is $k^3/(kh)\to\infty$ as $h\to 0$.

Comment: @LeonidKovalev That's the main point. If I would define $f$ for all $h,k\in\mathbb{R}$ the counterexample wouldn't work as you mentioned. Because the function is just defined on $A \cup B$ there is no possibility to fix an $k\in A$ and take a very small $h\notin A$ so that $k+h\in A \cup B$. If $k+h\in A$ then we have automatically $k\in A$ and $h\in A$. Because every point $x$ of $A\cup B$ is a limit point of $A\cup B\setminus \{x\}$ the concept if derivation is well defined for $f$.

Comment: @tampis. Interesting, but I think your $f$ is differentiable at $x=0$. Indeed, both the expression for the 'double increment quotient' are approaching $0$ as $|(h,k)|\to0$. Yes, $f$ has lots of discontinuity jumps around $0$, but that doesn't matter. Also the function $f(x)=x^3\chi_{\mathbb{Q}}$ is discontinuous everywhere outside the origin, but it's two times differentiable at $x=0$...

Comment: @bartgol You are right: $f$ is differentiable at $x=0$, but just in $x=0$ and therefore in no neighborhood of $x=0$. So the first derivative just exists in $x=0$ and is thus the function $f':\{0\}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}:0\mapsto 0$. Because there is no derivative defined for a function which is just defined in one point, the second derivative does not exists (which is defined as the derivative of the first derivative). What you mean is the concept of "pointwise second derivative" which Leonid Kovalev already mentioned in a comment to Christian's answer.

Comment: If a function is not defined on an open interval containing $0$, it automatically fails the definition given by @bartgol. The definition says, in part ... $\forall \underline{h}\in\mathbb{R}^2\cap \mathcal{B}(\underline{0},\delta)\setminus\underline{0}$ (some inequality holds). You can't claim that an inequality holds when its left-hand side is not even defined.

Comment: @LeonidKovalev I read the definition $\forall \underline{h}\in\mathbb{R}^2\cap \mathcal{B}(\underline{0},\delta)\setminus\{\underline{0}\} : A(\underline{h}, \delta, \epsilon)$ as $\forall \underline{h}\in(D^2\cap \mathcal{B}(\underline{0},\delta))\setminus\{\underline{0}\} : x+h_1+h_2 \in D \Rightarrow A(\underline{h}, \delta, \epsilon)$ where $D$ is the domain of the function. So somehow your are right. IMHO we have a new question: What is the expression of bartgol's approach for functions which are not defined on an open interval containing the considered point $x$?

Comment: @tampis I don't think there is an established concept of 2nd derivative at such a point. In fact, I'd say that the definition of 1st derivative that you stated in the question is not standard. IMHO it's overly permissive; there is a related [MSE thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/161910/most-general-a-subseteq-mathbb-r-to-define-derivative-of-f-a-to-mathbb-r)

Comment: @LeonidKovalev I have concreted my question. Now it's also okay to give an answer in the case where the function has to have an open domain. I also cleared thinks up in the community wiki post. I made clear that bartgol's idea still might work for functions defined on open subsets of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @LeonidKovalev: of course, if the function is not well definied in a neighborhood of the point where you compute the limit, then it does not make sense to compute the limit. However, I don't see how this applies to the counterexample you showed. Can you provide a function $f$ and a point $x_0$ such that my definition would give a wrong answer for the second derivative? I really can't see where it fails.

Comment: @bartgol I did not say that your definition fails. I wrote that "a function fails the definition", meaning it does not satisfy the definition. I'm pretty sure that your definition is a correct characterization of the second derivative. Someone should write a proof of that; someone with more time than I have at the moment.

Comment: I think you need to be more explicit about what sort of statement you want $A(\epsilon,\delta,f,x,c)$ to be.  Obviously you don't want it to be something like "$f$ is twice differentiable at $x$ and $f''(x)=c$."  But it has to be allowed to use quantifiers, so I'm not sure how to exclude that.

Answer (score 8):

I'm not sure, but I think there are two problems with the formula you used to approximate $f''(x_0)$:

- it uses the same discretization step for the approximation of the first and second derivative (it's like computing one directional derivative for a function of two variables: it might exist, but that does not imply that the differential exists).
- it's a centered finite difference formula, which therefore vanishes for a function that is odd around $x_0$ (or even gives infinity if $f$ is odd but $f(x_0)\neq0$, in which case $f$ is for sure discontinuous).

But I think the idea would work if the increments used in the approximation of the first and second derivative were different and the discretization formulas were not centered. Namely

$$f''(x)\simeq \frac{f'(x+h)-f'(x)}{h}$$

and then

$$f'(x+h)\simeq \frac{f(x+h+k)-f(x+h)}{k}$$
$$f'(x)\simeq \frac{f(x+k)-f(x)}{k}$$
which gives

$$f''(x)\simeq \frac{\dfrac{f(x+h+k)-f(x+h)}{k}-\dfrac{f(x+k)-f(x)}{k}}{h}=$$

$$f''(x)\simeq \frac{f(x+h+k)-f(x+h)-f(x+k)+f(x)}{hk}$$

Now, for the example reported in the link you gave, this formula does not give a finite result as $h,k$ go to $0$ *independently*.

To summarize, I would say that $f''$ exists and it's equal to $f''(x)$ if

$$\forall \varepsilon>0, \exists \delta>0 : \forall \underline{h}\in\mathbb{R}^2\cap \mathcal{B}(\underline{0},\delta)\setminus\underline{0}$$
$$\left|\frac{f(x+h_1+h_2)-f(x+h_1)-f(x+h_2)+f(x)}{h_1h_2}-f''(x)\right|<\varepsilon.$$

I'm not $100\%$ sure of this statement (in particular of the fact that the two increments have to independent), but it looks right to me. For sure you need not centered schemes though.

Comment: The centered difference formula is not a problem:  for the first derivative to exist it can't be odd around our point $x_0$ unless it is zero.  But you are right that $h$ and $k$ need to be able to vary independently.  The counterexample OP cites will fail in this case.

Comment: I think that if you use centered schemes, even if $h$ and $k$ are independent, the counterexample that tampis posted still holds (if I did my calculations correctly). But I will double check it.

Comment: I'm starting to believe that my definition of $f''$ in terms of $f$ is *too restrictive*. Indeed, if the condition above is satisfied $\forall\underline{h}\in\mathcal{B}(\underline{0},\delta)\setminus\underline{0}$, taking the limit as $h_1$ goes to zero, we have the definition of $f''$ as the limit of the increment quotient of $f'$. So if that definition is satisfied, then we are fine. However, it might be too restrictive. Indeed, $f''$ is defined as the limit of the increment quotient of $f'$, that is when '$h_1$ has been already sent to zero'...in some sense.

Comment: I really like your approach +1 Unfortunately I might have found a counterexample (see my last edit of the question).

Comment: The increments $h_1$ and $h_2$ do have to be independent; otherwise you just reduce to $\lim_{h\to 0} (f(x+2h)-2f(x+h)+f(x)/h^2$, which is not sufficient for the second derivative to exist; consider e.g. $f(x) = x^3\sin(1/x)$ (with $f(0)=0$).

Comment: However, even with independent increments, this definition does not even imply that $f$ is continuous at $x$, as pointed out by Tom Goodwillie in his answer to http://mathoverflow.net/questions/165704/non-continuous-higher-differentiability-ii --- if $f$ is a $\mathbb{Q}$-linear map $\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$, then the "second-order difference quotient" is identically zero.

Answer (score 5):

If we are not allowed to talk about $f'(x)$ for $x\ne x_0$ it is not possible to talk about $f''(x_0)$ in the proper sense. One could, however, approach the idea of $f''(x_0)$ via the Taylor expansion of $f$ at $x_0$:

The function $f$, defined in a neighborhood of $x_0$ has second derivative $b$ at $x_0$ if there is an $a\in{\mathbb R}$ such that
$$\lim_{h\to 0}{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)- a h \over h^2}={b\over2}\ .$$
This $\lim$-condition can obviously  be expanded into $\epsilon$-$\delta$-language.

Note, however, that the function $f(x):=x^3$ $(x\in{\mathbb Q})$ and $:=0$ $(x\notin{\mathbb Q})$ would have  $f''(0)=0$ according to this definition.

Comment: Indeed, this defines what is known as "pointwise second derivative" , which exists more often than $f''(x)$. However, I question why you say "not possible". @bartgol suggested a plausible definition in terms of a limit in $\mathbb R^2$. So far we have no proof that it works, but no counterexample either.

Comment: @Leonid Kovalev: Do you have any references for the concept of "pointwise second derivative$? A search in google just gave me links to articles which seemed to be really hard to understand for me.

Comment: @tampis Definition: $f$ has a pointwise derivative of order $k$ at point $a$ if there exists a polynomial $p$ of degree $k$ such that $\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)-p(x)}{(x-a)^k}=0$. If this holds, we define $f_{pt}^{(k)}(a)=p^{(k)}(a)$. When $k=1$, this is the same notion as $f'(a)$; but for $k>1$ the existence of $f_{pt}^{(k)}(a)$ does not imply the existence of $f^{(k)}(a)$... You will not find this notion in elementary textbooks, because it's not needed there. But there are situations, such as investigation of nonsmooth convex functions in $\mathbb R^n$, when it becomes useful (with $k=2$).

Comment: @user31373 :  It seems to me that this definition should explicitly require $f$ to be continuous at $a$; the definition as you state it says nothing at all about $f(a)$, but we cannot recreate the usual notion for $k = 1$ without this.  (Then pointwise differentiability is weaker than differentiability for $k > 1$, equivalent for $k = 1$, and stronger for $k = 0$, since even 0-times pointwise differentiability explicitly requires continuity.)

Comment: While I'm commenting, I like to think that the $pt$ in $f^{(k)}_{pt}$ stands for Peano–Taylor; the fact that the pointwise derivative equals the derivative when the latter exists is essentially Taylor's theorem with the Peano form of the remainder.  (The polynomial $p$ in user31373's definition must be the $k$th-order Taylor polynomial.)

Answer (score 4):

In this community wiki post I want to collect all progress we made so far in answering this question. Please feel free to edit it and to extend it with your ideas (you can also start a new community wiki post if you have a new approaches)

### Notes

- To proof the differentiability of the function in a neighborhood of $x$ one might find the following article interesting: [How to proof the convergence of functions without knowing the limit](http://kulla.me/de/artikel/alternative_existence_proof_of_function_limits/)

### Some approaches

- I know the formula $f''(x) = \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x+h)-2f(x)+f(x-h)}{h^2}$ but this limit does not provide the existence of the second derivative (see [section “limit” of wikipedia article “second derivative”](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_derivative#Limit)). So we cannot derive an epsilon-delta definition from the limit $\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x+h)-2f(x)+f(x-h)}{h^2}$.
- There is the idea to apply the above epsilon-delta definition to the first derivative:

  $$\forall \epsilon > 0\, \exists \delta > 0\, \forall y \in D\setminus \{x\}:|y-x|<\delta \Rightarrow \left|\frac{f'(y)-f'(x)}{y-x}-f''(x)\right|<\epsilon$$

  But then we already used the existence of the first derivative in our definition. To be a definition we shall conclude from it, that the function is differentiable in a  neighborhood of $x$ (This might be hard, I know ;-) ).
- There is the approach by [Christian Blatter](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/1303/christian-blatter) to define the second derivative from the taylor series $f(x_0+h)=f(x_0)+f'(x)h+\tfrac 12 f''(x) h^2$, so that it should be the limit

  $$\lim_{h\to 0}2\cdot {f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)- a h \over h^2}=b$$

  whereby $a$ shall be the unique number for which the above limit exists. Unfortunately the function $f(x) := \begin{cases} x^3 & ;x\in\mathbb{Q} \\ 0&;x\notin\mathbb{Q} \end{cases}$ is a function which is not differentiable in a neighborhood of $x$ but the above limit exists for $a=0$. (Notice: the above formula gives a definition for the "pointwise second derivative", please see the comment of Leonid Kovalev)

### bartgol's approach

[bartgol](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/33868/bartgol) has the following idea (see his answer):

$$\forall \varepsilon>0, \exists \delta>0 : \forall (h,k)\in\mathbb{R}^2\cap \mathcal{B}(\underline{0},\delta)\setminus\underline{0}$$
$$\left|\frac{f(x+h+k)-f(x+h)-f(x+k)+f(x)}{hk}-f''(x)\right|<\varepsilon.$$

- [Harald Hanche-Olsen](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/23290/harald-hanche-olsen) mentioned the [double mean value theorem](http://www.math.ntnu.no/%7Ehanche/blog/doubly-mean.pdf) in the comments. For me it seems to have a somehow similar form as [bartgol's](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/33868/bartgol) idea.
- The counterexample $f(x) := \begin{cases} x^3 & ;x\in\mathbb{Q} \\ 0&;x\notin\mathbb{Q} \end{cases}$ does not work for this approach ;-) Let $x=0$, $k+h\in\mathbb{Q}$ with $k,h\notin\mathbb{Q}$. Then we have

  $$\begin{align}\frac{f(x+h+k)-f(x+h)-f(x+k)+f(x)}{hk}&=\frac{(h+k)^3}{hk}\\&=\frac{h^2}{k}+3h+3k+\frac{k^2}{h}\end{align}$$

  If we fix $h<\delta$ and let $k\rightarrow0$ the amount of $\frac{h^2}{k}$ will get arbitrary high, while $3h+3k+\frac{k^2}{h} \rightarrow 3h$ so that $\left|\frac{f(x+h+k)-f(x+h)-f(x+k)+f(x)}{hk}-f''(x)\right|$ cannot be smaller than $\varepsilon$.
- I wanted to find a proof that $f$ has to be differentiable in a neighborhood of $x$. Therefore there has to be an open interval $O$ so that for all $x+h\in D\cap O$ we have:

  $$\forall \epsilon > 0\, \exists \delta > 0\, \forall k,\tilde k\in\mathbb{R} : |k| < \delta \land |\tilde k |<\delta \land x+h+k,x+h+\tilde k\in D \Rightarrow \left|{f(x+h+k)-f(x+h) \over k} - {f(x+h+\tilde k)-f(x+h) \over \tilde k}\right|<\epsilon$$

  With the representation $f(k+h+k)=f(x+h)+f(x+k)-f(x)+f''(x)hk+R(h,k)$ ($|R(h,k)|<|\epsilon h k|$) I got

  $$\begin{align}&\left|{f(x+h+k)-f(x+h) \over k} - {f(x+h+\tilde k)-f(x+h) \over \tilde k}\right|\\=&\left|{f(x+k)-f(x)\over k }-{f(x+\tilde k)-f(x)\over \tilde k}+{R(h,k)\over k}-{R(h,\tilde k)\over \tilde k}\right|\end{align}$$

  If one can prove the differentiability of $f$ at $x$ the term ${f(x+k)-f(x)\over k }-{f(x+\tilde k)-f(x)\over \tilde k}$ can be made arbitrary small for $k,\tilde k\rightarrow 0$. Unfortunately we have $\left|{R(h,k)\over k}\right|<|\epsilon h|$so that we have no control over this term if $k$ goes to zero.
- *My* interpretation of bartgol's idea for arbitrary functions is (let be $f:D\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$): Forall $\epsilon > 0$, there is a $\delta > 0$, so that for all $x+h+k\in D$ with $|h|+|k|<\delta$ we have

  $$f(x+h+k)=f(x+h)+f(x+k) -f(x)+f''(x)hk+R(h,k)$$

  so that $|R(h,k)|<|\varepsilon h k|$.

  - There is a counterexample for *the above* interpretation of bartgol's idea (Please notice, that bartgol's idea may still work for functions with open domains): Let $A:=\{q\cdot\pi : q\in\mathbb{Q}\}$ and $B:=\{q\cdot\sqrt{2} : q\in\mathbb{Q}\}$. $A$ and $B$ are abelian groups with $+$ as group operation and $A\cap B=\{0\}$. If we just consider $k,h\in (A \cup B)\setminus\{0\}$ we have $k+h\in A \Rightarrow k\in A \land h \in A$ and $k+h\in B \Rightarrow k\in B \land h \in B$. Now we define $f:A\cup B\rightarrow \mathbb{R}: x \mapsto \begin{cases} x^3 & ;x\in A\setminus\{0\} \\ 0 & ; x\in B\end{cases}$. For $x=0$ we have either:

    $$\begin{align}\left|\frac{f(x+h+k)-f(x+h)-f(x+k)+f(x)}{hk}\right|&=\left|\frac{(h+k)^3-h^3-k^3}{hk}\right|\\&=\left|3h+3k\right|\\&\le 3 (|h|+|k|)\end{align}$$

    or

    $$\left|\frac{f(x+h+k)-f(x+h)-f(x+k)+f(x)}{hk}\right|=\left|\frac{0}{hk}\right|=0$$

    This proves that the above statement is true for $f$ with $f''(0)=0$. Because $A$ and $B$ are dense in $\mathbb{R}$ the concept of derivation is well defined for $f$. But because there are noncontinuous jumps in every neighborhood of a point $x\in A \cup B\setminus \{0\}$ the function $f$ is not differentiable in a neighborhood of $x=0$.
- Actually, this definition does not work for functions defined on open domains either.  Consider a $\mathbb{Q}$-linear function $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$.  Then $f(x+h+k)-f(x+h)-f(x+k)+f(x)$ is identically zero, so this definition would give $f''(0)=0$; but such a function need not even be continuous.  This was pointed out by Tom Goodwillie [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/165704/non-continuous-higher-differentiability-ii).  He did show, however, that this definition does work if we assume that $f$ is differentiable in a neighborhood.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an enhancement of bartgol's idea which also implies that the function is differentiable at $x$.  There is a number $a$ such that $\forall \epsilon>0 \;\exists \delta>0$ such that if $h^2 h^k + v^2 <\delta$, then

$$ \Big| f(x+h+k+v) - f(x+h) - f(x+k) + f(x) - c h k - a v \Big| < \epsilon. $$

Letting $v=0$ we recover bartgol's definition.  But letting $h=k=0$, we recover the statement that $f$ is differentiable at $x$ with derivative $a$.  Therefore, if $f$ satisfies this definition, then it is differentiable at $x$; and furthermore *if* it is differentiable in some neighborhood of $x$, then it is twice differentiable at $x$ and $f''(x)=c$.