# Can a function be differentiable at the end points of its (closed interval) domain?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

Assume $f$ has a domain of $[a,b]$. Is it possible that $f$ is differentiable on the closed interval $[a,b]$, or must the maximal domain for $f'$ be $(a,b)$?

Comment: It is common to say that a function $f : [a, b] \to\mathbb R$ is differetiable at $a$ (or $b$) if $f$ can be extended to a function $g : (c, d)\to \mathbb R$ for some $(c, d)$ containing $[a, b]$, and $g$ is differentiable at $a$ (or $b$)

Comment: Depends exactly on what you mean. At first differentiability is only defined for interior points. However, one is then typically introduced to the concept of lateral derivative and with that the definition of differentiability is extended to the end points.

Answer (score 18):

It depends on the definition of differentiability you have. Some textbooks only define it for interior points. But there is also a more general definition (see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/162172/32951) for references):

> A function $f: A \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is differentiable for an accumulation point $a \in A$ of $A$ with derivative $f^\prime(a)$, iff for each $x_n \rightarrow a$ with $x_n\in A\setminus\{a\}$ you have $f^\prime(a) = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{f(x_n)-f(a)}{x_n-a}$.

So the answer is yes: You can define the derivative in a way, such that $f'$ is also defined for the end points of a closed interval. Note that for some theorem like the mean value theorem you only need continuity at the end points of the interval.

Comment: @StephenKulla: I'm very interested in the text you've seen this definition in. I've never seen it before. Do you remember where you've seen it?

Comment: @SOULed_Outt See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/162172/32951

Comment: @StephanKulla: can you explain what an accumulation point is? Apparently it's somewhat similar to the limit, but it also seems to be related to topology, which I know nothing of.

Comment: @HarryHolmes It is a point $x$ for which you find a sequence $(x_n)$ with all $x_n \in A \setminus \{x\}$ and $\lim x_n = x$