# Differentiability at a point x=0

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I road in a book that the function $f(x)=\sqrt{x} \sin(x)$ is differentiable at 0.
Personally, I don't think so since f is undefined on the left of $x=0$.
Can you confirm my thought or the book?

Comment: Maybe the author is talking about one-side differentiability?

Comment: See this related question: [Can a function be differentiable at the end points of its (closed interval) domain?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1295181/can-a-function-be-differentiable-at-the-end-points-of-its-closed-interval-doma).

Answer (score 2):

Since your domain is $[0,\infty )$  we only have  one sided derivative and that is what the book meant by differentiability at $0.$

Now to see if f(x) is indeed differentiable, we look at the difference quotient $$\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}$$ and let $x\to  0^+$. Since $f(0)=0$ the difference quotient simplifies to $$ \frac{sin(x)}{x} \sqrt {x}$$ which approaches $1\times 0=0$ as $x\to  0^+$.