# What sets can we define continuity and differentiability on?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, continuity

I am an undergraduate Physics student (completing my first year shortly) who has had a (first) course on Calculus, and another on Linear Algebra.

When working with differential equations (in physical problems), I decided to look with mathematical rigour what I was dealing with. So I decided to start with the beginning. The following questions popped up.

Let $\Bbb{F=R}$ or $\Bbb{C}$.

### Generalising Intervals

What is the concept parallel to an interval in $\Bbb{R}$, in $\Bbb{C}$? (Note: I’m not looking for contours, rather something which generalises the “rectanglular” and “circular” domains.)
Can the answer be open *or* closed subsets of $\Bbb{C}$? Can it be generalised to $\Bbb{F}^n$?

### Generalising Continuity and Differentiability

Suppose we have a subset $S\subseteq \Bbb{F}$. What properties must $S$ have so that *some form* of continuity and differentiability can be defined on *some* subset $\mathcal{S} \subseteq S$?
(See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/126192/673223) (later in the post) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1295218/673223).)
(I’d appreciate if your answer is generalisable to $\Bbb{F}^n$.)

### Extending *Normal* Calculus

For such a “continuous and differentiable” $\mathcal{S} \subseteq S$, what theorems of *normal* calculus will apply?
Also, how will the integral, if needed, be redefined?

### Finally, ODE’s

Now turning to ODE’s, I found a very satisfying definition of an ODE [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/93899/673223). But unfortunately, it is restricted to *intervals* of $\Bbb{R}$. How can you generalise this definition to $\Bbb{C}$? (That’s why I was asking for generalisation of interval.)

Very importantly, can we have solutions to ODE’s **not** as “intervals”, but sets like $\mathcal{S}$ above?

Comment: "How can you generalise this definition to $\mathbb C$?" There appears to be a notion of a [complex differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_differential_equation). I don't know anything about it but it seems to fit the bill.

Answer (score 2):

This is well-trodden ground in mathematical analysis. You should be able to find this information in nearly any text which covers multivariable calculus. See for example Chapter 3 of Apostol's *Mathematical Analysis*: Point Set Topology.

Point Set Topology is the field of mathematics that generalises notions of "interval" and "continuity", even beyond $\Bbb R^n$ and $\Bbb C^n$.

Differentiability has a number of generalisations, from gradients (in $\Bbb R^n$), which you will see *a lot* of in Physics, to the more abstract Fréchet derivative, which again works in more general spaces than $\Bbb R^n$.

Differentiability of complex functions is surprisingly different to the real case. A classic reference for this is Ahlfors' *Complex Analysis*. It covers a lot of ground and rigorously.

Not sure how much that will help in the direction of complex ODE's. But for the real case, when you add dimensions, you involve *partial* derivatives and end up with *partial differential equations* (PDE's). These are notoriously complicated to solve, but they can still be fruitfully studied. A search for "introduction to PDE's" or "first course in PDE's" will help. I don't want to recommend anything specifically, since I don't know the area.

I hope this gives you some ideas of where to look.

**Update**
Section 4 of Chapter 8 (Global Analytic Functions) of Ahlfors’ *Complex Analysis* is dedicated to linear complex differential equations. At least the material figures in the 3rd edition (1979).

Comment: Point me to a good *complete* text (or piecewise complete) that covers this rigorously.

Comment: And what about ODE’s?

Comment: Ok, read the *rest* of Apostol. Another rigorous and thorough text (thought advanced) is Rudin's *Real and Complex Analysis*. I'm not too familiar with ODE's, but a quick google search should turn up books and lecture notes which should give you an idea.

Comment: Google didn’t show up much, maybe I was typing in the wrong things.