# The second derivative as a limit

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

It is well-known that if $f$ is twice differentiable at $a$, then

$$ f''(a) = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(a+2h)-2f(a+h) + f(a)}{h^2}. $$

See e.g. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/210264/second-derivative-formula-derivation) or [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/477841/second-derivative-of-class-c2-expressed-as-limit).

On the other hand, the RHS limit may exist without $f$ being twice differentiable.  For instance, if $f(x) = x^3 \sin(1/x)$ for $x\neq 0$ and $f(0)=0$, then at $a=0$ the RHS is $2h(4\sin(1/2h) - \sin(1/h))$, which has limit $0$; but this function $f$ is not twice differentiable at $0$.

My question is, under what additional hypotheses can we conclude from the existence of the RHS limit that $f$ is twice differentiable?

We probably need to assume that $f$ is once differentiable on a neighborhood of $a$, but that is not sufficient since the counterexample above is in fact smooth at all points $x\neq 0$.  For the same reason, it is not sufficient to assume that the above limit exists for all $a$ in some neighborhood.

Note that this is not the same as [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/159473/is-there-an-epsilon-delta-definition-of-the-second-derivative), which is asking for a limit definition of the second derivative that doesn't require extra hypotheses; here I'm asking what extra hypotheses can be added to this particular definition to make it work.

Comment: Without looking into it, I'd assume that we need the limit to exist  and be continuous (w.r.t. $a$) in a neighbourhood around the relevant point.

Comment: @Arthur that was my first guess at a stronger condition that eliminates the particular counterexample, but I don't have any other reason to believe that it would suffice.

Comment: Do you really mean a _forward_ difference in the numerator ?

Comment: @TonyPiccolo what do you mean?

Comment: Why don't you consider the 2nd order _symmetric_ derivative ?

Comment: @TonyPiccolo My best guess is that you're thinking of replacing the numerator with $f(x+h)-2f(x)+f(x-h)$. That has the problem that it equals zero whenever f is an odd function around x.

Comment: Can you explain why that is a problem ?

Comment: @TonyPiccolo Many odd functions are not twice differentiable.

Comment: The same thing happens for the example in your question ...

Comment: @TonyPiccolo I really don't understand what you're getting at. I'm asking a question. You seem to be suggesting that I should have asked a different question. Well, this is the question that I'm asking. If you want to know about symmetric second differences, you can ask another question.

Comment: I cannot understand why, after producing the limit of a difference quotient, you suggest two links that speak of another. I thought it was clear.

Comment: @TonyPiccolo Oh, is that all? It's basically the same proof in both cases, and one of the links mentions both. In fact, I suspect that the answer to this question, if there is one, will work in both cases too. I just chose the version I did because it works as-is in slightly more cases.

Comment: I agree and find the question very interesting.

Comment: The function $f(x)=x^3\sin(1/x)$ is twice differentiable at $x=0$.  But it is not twice continuously differentiable at $x=0$.